# Generate cryptographic-secure random numbers within a natively-compiled procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, sql-server-2017

I need to generate salt values for a hash operation.

Generating these salts within the database is perfect for my situation - it would be much more complicated (and bug-prone/security risk) to generate these salt values elsewhere (e.g., client-side)

To make things easier for myself, I have written some procedures to generate random numbers of various types. (`BIGINT`, `INT`, etc.)

Obviously, these procedures could easily be modified to produce any size chunk of random bytes, but `BIGINT` is my focus for now.

The problem I'm running into, is that `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` can only be used in non-native contexts.

I have both native and non-native operations that need to use random numbers, and they all need to be secure.

My workaround right now, is to use `NEWID` in the native version (see code below), but this is known to be non-secure, and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Is there a way to generate cryptographic random numbers in native procedures?

```
--non-native, cryptographic
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RandomBigInt]
    @result BIGINT OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    SET @result = CAST ( CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM ( 8 ) AS BIGINT ) ;
END
GO

--native, non-cryptographic
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NativeRandomBigInt]
    @result BIGINT OUTPUT
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION ,
     SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH ( TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT   ,
                       LANGUAGE                    = N'English' )
    SET @result = CAST ( CAST ( NEWID ( ) AS BINARY ( 8 ) ) AS BIGINT ) ;
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `all need to be secure`.

Comment: @Alex I have multiple T-SQL operations, some native and some non-native, each with multiple sets of procedures, which require random number generation, and they all need random numbers to be cryptographically secure. Regular pseudo-random numbers (e.g. `NEWID`) will cause security problems (e.g. when salting hashes).

Comment: Unless you are a cryptography professional then anything you come up with will not be cryptographically secure.  Given that you are asking this question here, then you are not a cryptographic professional.  Sorry to give you the bad news.  The best you can do is probably as @Shnugo suggests and combine as many different pseudo-random sources as you can easily process.

Comment: @rossum Does writing my own stored procedures to implement raw crypto algorithms for AES/SHA3 operations count as being a crypto pro? Semi-pro? lol this isn't my first rodeo, if  I have to write my own custom natively-compiled crypto-rng, I can - I just really don't want to (actually I think I already have most of that code written somewhere, I should search my library). (Also generally a bad practice to roll your own crypto, if avoidable - as I'm sure you know.)

Comment: I don't know anything about MS products, but `NEWID` seems to be a GUID.  from a cryptographic perspective using something so deterministic seems bad (given a time and salt value from the same machine there are only ~30 bits of random state).  I'd try and have 128 or 256 bits of randomness so this isn't ever the "weakest link" in the system.  I've got similar experience and would call myself an amateur, I'd say pros are the people who design crypto systems and have them stand up to a few years of determined attack

Comment: @SamMason Yeah, I agree 100% (I'm obviously an amateur XD) `NEWID` is pretty much out of the question for salt values. I'm moving my data out of memory-optimized tables, back to the hard-disk - so I can keep using `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` to generate quality bits. I'm using a 256-bit salt against a 256-bit input value, and producing a 512-bit hash using SHA3. A mere 30-bits of randomness in a GUID is laughable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any *pseudo-random number* is not really random - as you obviously know...

One idea might be, to combine something **almost random** (the pseudo-random `NEWID()`) with something **really random** (the actual timestamp). The first does not meet your needs, the second is - at least in some figures - predictable. But together this may be a solution:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME2(7)=SYSUTCDATETIME(); --9 Bytes in memory, the first byte (the precision) will be cut off later
DECLARE @guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID();    --pseudo random

--We can cast the time value to a 9-byte-binary, take the right-most 8 byte and treat it as a BIGINT 
DECLARE @dtCasted BIGINT = CAST(RIGHT(CAST(@dt AS BINARY(9)),8) AS BINARY(8));
--And we take the first 8 byte of the GUID
DECLARE @guidCasted BIGINT = CAST(@guid AS BINARY(8));

--The combination is XORed and returned as a BIGINT
SELECT @dtCasted ^ @guidCasted
```

--This is the same as a one-liner:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(RIGHT(CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() AS BINARY(9)),8) AS BINARY(8)) AS BIGINT) ^ CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(8));
```

Comment: It looks like `NEWID` is just as good as `NEWID ^ timestamp`. According to `RFC4122`, (which `NEWID` complies with) the resulting `uniqueidentifier` already has the current timestamp embedded. So manually xoring the timestamp into the value afterwards might actually serve no purpose, and just add fruitless complication. It looks like I might have to pull my relevant data out of memory-optimized tables in order to maintain a higher level or security. (Unless there is another source of good entropy available that I can xor ... that could be interesting.)

Comment: @Giffyguy Okay, I never had to deal with such a high level of security requirements. a `NEWID()` was enough for me. So I did not read about the details... Something fairly random might be the time consumed by a simple action. This will highly depend on the machine's current duties. `DATETIME2` goes down to 100 ns...

Comment: `time consumed by a simple action` That's a pretty good idea. I'll look into that.